# Will Bootstrap still load hidden responsive classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, hidden

I'm trying to optimise my website so it also displays nicely on mobile. 
Now in order to do so correctly or so it looks nice, I will need to show for example an image on a different place on the mobile view.

Now I add the class .hidden-xs and .visible-xs on one of each place where I need to have the same image.

The question is, since I now call the image twice from the database will my browser load the page slower?

If this is the case, how can I solve this problem then?

Comment: Are you sure it's necessary to have the same image two times on the page?  It's less maintainable that way.  Could you use the grid class with push and pull to adjust the source order and layout for your mobile design?  If you post some code, perhaps others could provide better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both images will be loaded, so it can potentially take longer to load the page even if you are using the responsive classes. One possible solution is to load the images via css as background images, with each sized image in a different media query. There are also javascript solutions out there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the same file is loaded twice, it won't make much difference, if any. As an example, see these [example1](http://www.bootply.com/HVqDZDCWnw), [example2](http://www.bootply.com/upmgb3K3WU).

**EDIT: I originally just alluded to the javascript option below, but I got curious and now put together a solution for it, with help from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947243/replace-part-of-filename-with-javascript):**

If two *different files* are loaded, some javascript that only loads the bigger file when it's needed would keep your mobile load times lower: [Example](http://www.bootply.com/Y8XECJpGjS)

HTML:

```
<div class="visible-sm">
  <img src="...example-image_small.jpg" />
</div>
...
<div class="hidden-sm">
  <img src="...example-image_small.jpg" />
<div>
```

Javascript:

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    $("img[src$='_small.jpg']").each(function() {
        var new_src = $(this).attr("src").replace('_small', '_large'); 
        $(this).attr("src", new_src); 
    });
}
```

If you've got image files named properly (ending in _small and _large) it all falls into place. It is worth noting that the small image will always load, which means on bigger screens you will load both, but on bigger screens that should be easier to handle.