# Replace part of filename with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, responsive-design

I want to load different images based on screensize, and thought replacing text in a filename with javascript would do the trick elegantly, as long as I've got corresponding images properly named. I'm close with this, but close won't cut it.

http://jsfiddle.net/B7QhZ/2/

Javascript:

```
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
    $("div:contains(_small.jpg)").html(function (i, currentVal) {
        return currentVal.replace("_small.jpg", "_large.jpg");
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="...test-image_small.jpg" />
```

As you can see in my fiddle, i've got it working on text, but not the filename.

ps - I specifically **don't** want to load images as background-image in media-queried classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete function:

```
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
    $("img[src$='_small.jpg']").each(function() {
        var new_src = $(this).attr("src").replace('_small', '_large'); 
        $(this).attr("src", new_src); 
    }); 

} else {
    alert('Less than 960');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to load images based on screensize

Set the `width` and `height` of `CSS` for `div` to 100%

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/B7QhZ/12/)

Comment: *different* images for different screensize. i'll update the question to clarify